# Disabling order from belongsto array in just one function

Tags: sql, model, sql-order-by, cakephp-1.3

I have a belongsTo array in my `gal_provider` model as below:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'User.name'
        ),
 )
```

And most of the functions inluded in the model `gal_provider` requires to sort the results according to the user names. But there is a function called `recevtProviders()` does not require this order. So I tried

```
$order = "";
$gal_providers = $this->find("all",array("conditions"=>$conditions,"recursive"=>$recursive,
            "fields"=>$fields,"limit"=>$limit,"order"=>$order));
```

BUt the query generated still shows `ORDER BY "User.name"`. How can I disable this `order` only from this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the order parameter you're passing is only going to affect the gal_provider model. Try this just before your find call to remove the order from the associated model:

```
$this->belongsTo['User']['order'] = '';
```

Also, if you're not using it, Containable is a very useful behavior. Using containable, the order on the User model could be disabled like this:

```
$this->find("all",array("conditions"=>$conditions,"recursive"=>$recursive,
            "fields"=>$fields,"limit"=>$limit,"order"=>$order,"contain" => array("User" => array("order" => ""))));
```